# Big Omega Proof for $5^n = \Omega(6^n)$

Tags: proof-writing, computer-science, bounded-variation

I got the Big-O ($\mathcal{O}$) proof but I am having troubles with the Big Omega ($\Omega$) proof. I am trying to prove $6^n$ is not the tightest bound for $5^n$. Is this logic true: $7^n$, $8^n$ would be a tighter bound than $6^n$? If that is true then I think I got the answer. If not can someone lead me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $6^n/5^n=1.2^n\rightarrow\infty$ as $n$ gets large, so $5^n$ cannot be big-omega of $6^n$.

Comment: I was also about to write that, but I'm guessing he confused Big Omega with Big Theta. His original message was titled "Big Theta proof", but then he talked about Big Omega in the text. Really confusing.